# How to disable dialog alert and close the website in window.onbeforeunload?

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

How can I disable dialog alert and close the website in `window.onbeforeunload`?

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  var isVisible = $('#submitbtn').is(':visible');
  if(isVisible==true){
    return null;
  }else{
    return 'you havent close';
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`return undefined;` to prevent dialog while `window.onbeforeunload`

**Demo:-**

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  var isVisible = $('#submitbtn').is(':visible');
  if (isVisible == true) {
    $(window).unbind();
    return undefined;
    //is there any way to disable dialog alert and close the website??
  } else {
    return 'you havent close';
  }
};
$('#hidebtn').on("click",function(){
  $('#submitbtn').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="httpp://google.com">Leave page</a>
<input type="button" id="submitbtn" value="You will not get the dialog untill i am visible" />
<input type="button" id="hidebtn" value="hide/show" />
```

Comment: thanks for your quick reply... actually I have call a function before return null; if I changed it to return undefined; it will not run that function......

Comment: is there any way to trigger user close the window and run something without any dialog or alert??

Comment: Yes you can call any function before `return undefined;` but it should not contain a confirm or alert. thats a limitation

Comment: yeah it worked for me.... but I need to add alert(''); before return undefined;...... if I havent add alert before return undefined; it will close window without call my function.......any ways to fix it??

Comment: Click the hide/show button in the demo. I thinik that is the one you want